# Pressed super + p

Tags: shortcut-keys, display, mouse-pointer

I pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on my keyboard and now Ubuntu isn't recognizing one of my two monitors and I am not able to click on anything. The only thing that seems to be functioning is the mouse cursor.

Comment: What's SUPER+P supposed to do? I'm on 17.10 and nothing apparent happens when I press it. I just have one monitor, though.

Comment: @PerlDuck I ended up re-installing Ubuntu to fix this, I had some work I needed to get done so I really didn't have a lot of time to do a lot of investigation. But I did come across a blog that references this 'bug' [click here to see the blog](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-314.html).

Comment: @David Foerster, thank you for editing my comment. This is actually my first time posting. I like this community already :)

Comment: @swaggindragon's blog post is a dead link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by pressing again same <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
It will back to normal (tried in Ubuntu 16.04).